# How do I programmatically find the path to sibling projects in the same solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

What I want to do: Run `Program.cs` in `Project_1`, which creates a new text-file in `Project_2`.

Requirements:

- Platform-agnostic path-separators (no hard-coded `/` or `\\`)
- No absolute paths (Solution-folder should be considered the root-folder)

Given this solution-structure:

```
Solution_1
|
├── Project_1
│   ├── Program.cs
│   └── Project_1.csproj
|
└── Project_2
    └── Project_2.csproj
```

After running `Program.cs`, I want `Project_2` to look like this:

```
Solution_1
|
├── Project_1
│   ├── Program.cs
│   └── Project_1.csproj
|
└── Project_2
    ├── Project_2.csproj
    └── TextFile.txt
```

Now, what I can't seem to be able to dig out of the [Environment-documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment(v=vs.110).aspx) is the answer to the following question:

*"How can I access the path of the sibling project `Project_2`, relative to the Solution root so that it doesn't break when installed on different systems?"*

My best solution so far would be something like wrapping `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` in *n* number of `Directory.GetParent()`-calls, but it requires me to know exactly how many levels we need to climb, and will change based on the path of the running executable.

NB: I am aware that it would be easier to just reference `Project_1` from `Project_2` and run the code and write the file from the same project, but I am trying to get around this without making `Project_2` dependent on `Project 1`.

What is the recommended way of finding the path to a sibling project?

Comment: "but I am trying to get around this without making Project_2 dependent on Project 1" - except you are. Whether it's formally linked via Add New Reference, or informally linked by being required to be deployed alongside it. Project 1 still depends on Project 2.

Comment: Why not just have a configuration option in Project1 which says where to store the file - much more flexible!

Comment: @mason It isn't. Project_2 is a library, and Project_1 updates it. Users don't need to reference Project_1 in order to use the Project_2 library

Comment: What do you have against referencing Project 2 from Project 1?

Comment: @RB That is certainly an option, but I couldn't figure out how to provide a string with a relative path as a setting or configuration property

Comment: @krystah 1) If it's a config option, it doesn't have to be a relative path. (2) By default, non-rooted paths are treated as relative to the working directory in all the file-based .NET APIs I can think of, so you shouldn't need to do anything special anyway (although I can't confirm that without seeing your actual file-writing code)

Comment: @mason I don't mind making Project 1 dependent on Project 2, but I don't understand how a project reference will provide me with the path, accessible as a string from Program.cs

Comment: Once Project 2 is referenced from Project 1, the DLL of Project 2 gets included in Project 1, it becomes part of the project as far as the code is concerned. So there's really no need to "find the path to Project 2" because you can put the text file anywhere you like.

Comment: @RB True, but the root of the relative path at runtime changes based on execution environment (debug/release), doesn't it?

Comment: No (well, yes, but not for the reason you think it does!) - the root of the relative path typically changes based on what is the Working Directory. For example, open up a command prompt and navigate to `c:\temp`. Then run `C:\source\stuff\mytool\bin\debug\mytool.exe`. The working directory will be `C:\temp`. If you aren't aware of what a working directory is, please read up on it, as it's pretty important to what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: @RB I know what a working directory is. What I'm referring to is that most of the developers using this tool will be using it from Visual Studio, and based on whatever Run-configuration they're using, the path may change (`bin/debug`/`bin/release`). That's why I wanted to specify the absolute path, relative to the current solution.

Comment: @krystah Um - I think I might have misunderstood you then - can you edit your question to explain what Project1 does and why it is run from Visual Studio? Perhaps explain how it is executed as well - is it a console application executed by clicking "Start", or something else? Does it hook into the Visual Studio plugin environment (EnvDTE) or similar?

Comment: That's a good question I haven't really considered, it's just the way we're used to do it. A post-build event to move the executable would nullify a lot of the concerns regarding a changing working directory, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @RB Yes, all the developers are running it by clicking Start, and they're all using default build configurations